# Bootstrap <div> borders are crooked

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I created a form on a cshtml page that has fillable field, and then I export it to PDF. I styled the Bootstrap rows and columns with a border so it looks like a form we are modeling. I noticed that some of the borders don't line up right and seem crooked.
[image: Highlights in red]

I have a few css classes on the page to handle various borders that I turn on or off so the borders are not doubled up creating a thicker line

```
<style>
        .gridCellBorder{
            border-top-width: thin;
            border-left-width: thin;
            border-top-style:solid;
            border-left-style:solid;
        }
        .gridCellBorderLeftOnly {
            border-left-width: thin;
            border-left-style: solid;
        }
        .gridCellBorderRight {
            border-top-width: thin;
            border-left-width: thin;
            border-right-width: thin;
            border-top-style: solid;
            border-left-style: solid;
            border-right-style: solid;
        }
        .gridCellBorderLeftRightOnly {
            border-left-width: thin;
            border-right-width: thin;
            border-left-style: solid;
            border-right-style: solid;
        }
        .gridCellBorderRightOnly {
            border-top-width: thin;
            border-right-width: thin;
            border-top-style: solid;
            border-right-style: solid;
        }
    </style>
```

Here is a sample of my rows and columns code

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9 gridCellBorder">
                <h3 style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">RECORD OF WEIGHTED GUIDELINES APPLICATION</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 gridCellBorderRight"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 gridCellBorder">1. REPORT NO.</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 gridCellBorder">2. BASIC PROCUREMENT INSTRUMENT IDENTIFICATION NO.</div>
            <div class="col-md-2 gridCellBorder">3. SPIIN</div>
            <div class="col-md-2 gridCellBorderRight">4. DATE OF ACTION</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 gridCellBorder">
                @Html.EJS().InPlaceEditor("textReportNo").Mode(Syncfusion.EJ2.InPlaceEditor.RenderMode.Inline).Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.InPlaceEditor.InputType.Text).ShowButtons(false).SubmitOnEnter().Render()
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 gridCellBorder">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 gridCellBorder" style="font-size:small;">a. PURCHASING OFFICE</div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 gridCellBorder" style="font-size:small;">b. FY</div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 gridCellBorder" style="font-size:small;">c. TYPE PROC INST CODE</div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 gridCellBorderRight" style="font-size:small;">d. PRISN</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 gridCellBorderLeftOnly">
                        @Html.EJS().InPlaceEditor("textPurchasingOffice").Mode(Syncfusion.EJ2.InPlaceEditor.RenderMode.Inline).Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.InPlaceEditor.InputType.Text).ShowButtons(false).SubmitOnEnter().Render()
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 gridCellBorderLeftOnly">
                        @Html.EJS().InPlaceEditor("textFY").Mode(Syncfusion.EJ2.InPlaceEditor.RenderMode.Inline).Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.InPlaceEditor.InputType.Text).ShowButtons(false).SubmitOnEnter().Render()
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 gridCellBorderLeftOnly">
                        @Html.EJS().InPlaceEditor("textTypeProcInstCode").Mode(Syncfusion.EJ2.InPlaceEditor.RenderMode.Inline).Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.InPlaceEditor.InputType.Text).ShowButtons(false).SubmitOnEnter().Render()
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 gridCellBorderLeftOnly">
                        @Html.EJS().InPlaceEditor("textPrisn").Mode(Syncfusion.EJ2.InPlaceEditor.RenderMode.Inline).Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.InPlaceEditor.InputType.Text).ShowButtons(false).SubmitOnEnter().Render()
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 gridCellBorder">
                @Html.EJS().InPlaceEditor("textSpiin").Mode(Syncfusion.EJ2.InPlaceEditor.RenderMode.Inline).Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.InPlaceEditor.InputType.Text).ShowButtons(false).SubmitOnEnter().Render()
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 gridCellBorderRight">
                @Html.EJS().InPlaceEditor("dateOfAction").Mode(Syncfusion.EJ2.InPlaceEditor.RenderMode.Inline).Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.InPlaceEditor.InputType.Date).ShowButtons(false).SubmitOnEnter().Render()
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 gridCellBorder">5. CONTRACTING OFFICE CODE</div>
            <div class="col-md-1 gridCellBorder"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 gridCellBorder"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2 gridCellBorderRight"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 gridCellBorderLeftOnly">
                @Html.EJS().InPlaceEditor("textContractOfficeCode").Mode(Syncfusion.EJ2.InPlaceEditor.RenderMode.Inline).Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.InPlaceEditor.InputType.Text).ShowButtons(false).SubmitOnEnter().Render()
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 gridCellBorderLeftOnly">ITEM</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 gridCellBorderLeftOnly">COST CATEGORY</div>
            <div class="col-md-2 gridCellBorderLeftRightOnly">OBJECTIVE</div>
        </div>
```

I thought design would be flexible for variable rows and columns by using Bootstrap, but I am wondering it the styles would be easier and cleaner using tables.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Two questions:
1. Does it render crooked only in the PDF or also on the web page?
2. If you change the zoom in the PDF, does it affect how crooked the borders look?

Comment: The snapshot above is the web page. I have not completed the pdf output yet.